# Why Dlink DIR-615 T3 is not working as repeater with ZTE F670LV9.0 Main Router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, dhcp, repeater

I am currently using a ZTE F670LV9.0 router as my main router with a default gateway of 192.168.1.1 and a DHCP server pool ranging from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.250. My goal is to utilize my old D-Link router (Model: DIR-615; Hardware Version: T3) as a wireless repeater to extend my Wi-Fi network range. Despite configuring the D-Link router with specific settings, I am encountering connectivity issues, and it remains unable to connect to the internet.

Steps Taken to Configure the D-Link Router as a Repeater:

1. **Disabled DHCP:** In the D-Link router's settings, I disabled the DHCP server to prevent IP address conflicts with the main router.
2. **Assigned IP Address:** I assigned a static IP address to the D-Link router, specifically 192.168.1.254. I also attempted to assign an IP address within the range of 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.250, but this approach did not yield successful results.
3. **Wireless Configuration:** I selected and authenticated the correct SSID (Wi-Fi network name) of my ZTE F670LV9.0 main router during the setup process on the D-Link router.
4. **Rebooted the Repeater:** After making these configuration changes, I rebooted the D-Link router to apply the settings.

Despite these efforts, the D-Link router, configured as a repeater, is still unable to establish a connection to the internet.

Additional Information:

- The ZTE F670LV9.0 main router operates as the DHCP server, managing IP address assignments for devices within the network.
- The D-Link router is intended to function as a repeater, extending the wireless signal of the main router to improve coverage in certain areas.

I seek guidance and assistance in resolving the issue to successfully configure the D-Link DIR-615 router as a wireless repeater and establish a reliable connection to the internet. Any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what way is it unable to connect to the internet? How did you test and what were the results? Is everything else working? For example, can you ping your main router through a device connected through the old router / repeater?

Comment: @Albin Hi, thanks for your reply. When I attempted to ping the main router, I received a "destination unreachable" message. I ensured that I correctly selected the desired SSID of the main router and entered the correct password during the setup process. Additionally, both routers are configured with the channel set to "auto."

Is there anything else I should check or consider to troubleshoot this issue further?

Comment: Moreover, for testing purposes, I replaced the main router with the hotspot from my mobile device. When I attempted to extend my mobile hotspot using the D-Link DIR-615 router, it worked perfectly. I was able to connect to the internet without any issues.

Here are the IP details for reference:

My mobile hotspot IP: 192.168.43.1
D-Link Router: 192.168.43.100
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
This suggests that the D-Link router itself is capable of functioning as a repeater when connected to my mobile hotspot. However, it's puzzling why it doesn't work with the ZTE F670LV9.0 router's network.

Comment: If you can not ping the main router, there must be s.th. wrong with the connection. What device are you using to do the ping? S.th. that is connected to the 2nd router? What's the device's IP and can you ping the 2nd router? Please add the information also to your question (including the info from your previous comments). A network diagram including the IP configuration would be helpful as well.